# apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6:

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, aws

> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This started after rebooting the server (`sudo reboot`).  I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS AMD64 server.  Have searched high and low and can't find a solution.  Can someone please please give me some directions?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to resolve the issue by simply copying libstdc++.so.6.0.19 from another installation and simply placing it in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder.  Right after that everything went back to normal.  I am still curious as to why a simple reboot would result in this nightmare.